# ReplaceAll error on trying to extract solutions the results of DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve symbolically a system of differential equations (simplified example):

```
fun[F_, P_, x0_, y0_, tau_, A_, t_] = 
  x /. 
    First[
      DSolve[
        {x'[t] == -F * (x[t] - y[t]) +  x[t] * A * Exp[-t/tau], 
         y'[t] == +F * (x[t] - y[t]) - P * (y[t] - y0), 
         x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, 
        {x, y}, t]]
```

which doesn't work:

> ReplaceAll: {(x^[Prime])[t]==A E^(-(t/tau)) x[t]-F y[t],(y^[Prime])[t]==F 
>   (x[t]-y[t]),x[0]==x0,y[0]==y0}is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing,

it only works if I take out the inhomogeneous term:

```
fun[F_, P_, x0_, y0_, tau_, A_, t_] = 
  x /. 
    First[
      DSolve[
        {x'[t] == -F * (x[t] - y[t]) +  x[t] * A, 
         y'[t] == +F * (x[t] - y[t]) - P * (y[t] - y0), 
         x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, 
        {x, y}, t]]
```

in which case works fine.

My question is: is this a mistake on my part or is this just because this goes beyond the capabilities of DSolve?

Comment: What does "which doesn't work" mean here? More details are likely necessary.

Comment: oops sorry , I forgot the error output

Comment: The problem is that the `DSolve[…]` expression stays unevaluated (because `DSolve` can't solve it) - this means that `First` returns the list of equations from the `DSolve[…]` expression, which is clearly not a valid replacement rule, hence the complaints from `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: So it doesn't give any error if it can't solve it?

Comment: @mmonti No, most functions in Mathematica do not return an error if they can solve something (exception being the numeric functions generally) - the idea is that the symbolic expression might still be of use (although this might be debatable for `DSolve`...) - consider e.g. `int = Integrate[E^Sin@x, x]` which stays unevaluated, but `D[int,x]` still returns the correct result